# wsdl2objc or sudzc with WCF message security

Tags: ios, wcf, wcf-security, sudzc, wsdl2objc

Is it possible to generate a client with wsdl2objc or sudzc to consume a WCF service with message security and session management?

If someone know some other tool that can achieve this let me know!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this challenge?

Comment: @JoelHansen Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WCF, message security is usually implemented using the soap ws-security standard. wsdl2objc does not seem to support any of the ws-security standard as far as I can tell.